# How do I get awk (gawk) to honor case as in IGNORECASE=0?

Tags: awk, gawk

I can't get GNU awk (gawk) to treat upper and lowercase input differently in regular expressions. The environment is Win32.

I upgraded to gawk 4.1

I saved the the input file as ANSI ASCII and as UTF-8 UNICODE from both Notepad and Notepad++

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

set the following environment variables before invoking gawk:

set LC_ALL=C

set LANG=C